# Track changes to Windows Update settings in registry

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log, windows-update

Is it possible to track down changes to the Windows Update settings in the event logs (Win2008 R2 Std)?

I tried filtering the System event log by Source = WindowsUpdateClient but this seems to list only actual Windows Update actions. I also tried filtering the Security event log but couldn't find any useful criteria for the question at hand.

Which event log should I query and how can I filter for changes to Windows Update settings?
Or would I need to configure a specific security auditing beforehand?

---

*Update*

Since WU settings are stored in the registry, my more precise question would be if it is possible to employ security auditing on the respective registry keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add Advanced Auditing to Windows (starting in Windows Server 2008) to monitor specific Registry keys/entries so that if they are modified, touched, etc. in any way, an event will be logged.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-registry

So in your case, you would want to monitor everything under the Windows Update related keys.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, changes to windows update settings are not logged.

But you can use GPO to set and lock windows update.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539(WS.10).aspx

Comment: We have locked the WU settings on our client machines via GPO but doing so on our servers is not an option.